# Infinite loop, how to know in Eclipse what code is running now?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse to run some android/java code in my device. Sometimes the code seems to be stuck in a loop. And sometimes it works. I was wondering, is there a way in eclipse where I can tell it to show my what is the current running? Or even last method called? I want to know where this "code stuck" is so I can fix it. Stepping in won't help as I need the code to run without stoppage for this to reproduce

Please help

Comment: What you have try ? can we have code please ?

Comment: Use logs in between loops.

Comment: use System.out.println(""); statements

Comment: Everything is possible, post your code to get better help sooner.

Comment: apply break points and and debug the program

Comment: Guys ! seriously! I think I made it clear that "stepping in" wont help as I have no idea what part of code is getting stuck (so no break points and no debug is usefull). And  I am sorry do you want me to post 3000 lines of code here and ask you to figure it out. My question was specifically about how to use eclipse effectively in situations like that. Thanks for whoever downvoted the question :(

Comment: Anyways @bidfx answered my question perfectly

Comment: I'm really not sure why this question was downvoted so much, or why it's "not a real question". I got here through a Google search, and it certainly helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run the app with eclipse debugger connected. When it got stuck click the suspend ("pause") button. Maybe you have to do some single-steps to jump out of some lib call and get to your code. In debug perspective you can see the call trace which tells you the function you're in.

Comment: Perfect , exactly what I am looking for. Didn't know about the suspend functionality in Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want or can't run the application in debug mode, you can use [Java VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), a tool that can be found at the `bin` folder of your installed JDK under the name `jvisualvm.exe`.

It provides you a way to see all the running threads, the methods that were called, and, on a case of a deadlock, it can help you to find out where it happens.

I never used this tool to monitor an application on other machine or even other device, but, I know that under "File" menu there is an option called "Add Remote Host...". Maybe, you can monitor you application from there.

Comment: Very good suggestion and I am not sure if it works on conencted device. I will try it. But I gave you an upvote for the suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks. Post back if it works! I'm curious now! :)